# Can't Swipe Due to editingStyleForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, editmode

There seems to be an error that's impossible to avoid, but I'm hoping someone can do the impossible.

In a UITableView editMode there's a lefthand delete indicator (red circle with a white line):

[image]

I just want the drag / drop grip on the right, so I get rid of the indicator by calling:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return .none
}
```

However, it also seems pretty clear that if you want the ability to swipe for actions...

[image]

You CANNOT call the above "editingStyleForRowAt" method. So it seems like I'm forced to choose only one of the above features... oddly you can only return ".none", ".insert", or ".delete".

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should try with custom cell.
Please check below link.

I just assume, it is work for you, I am not sure.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/eecellswipegesturerecognizer